# In Drupal 7, what events are logged?

Tags: log-messages

I'm looking for a list of the events that Drupal 7 logs via watchdog. The question I'm trying to answer for a colleague is this:

"What logging Drupal is capable of, specifically related to security, performance, and metrics?"

I realize that I can log whatever I like but I'm looking for the default list. Googling hasn't helped.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look through the list of Drupal core functions that call watchdog(), you can get a good idea of the events that get logged.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/calls/watchdog/7